# getting the details of .cer certifcate installed in java

Tags: java, keytool

I have one certicated installed in java that is at the below path in unix machine

```
/opt/app/acx/wer/tools/jdk1.5.0/jre/lib/security
```

now inside this there is a certicate installed with named **ertytr.cer** now please advise i want to check the details of this .cer extension certificate that is whenit is going to be expire and rest all other details of this certificates , please advise hwhat can be the command to get the detials of this certifactes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command from /opt/app/acx/wer/tools/jdk1.5.0/jre/lib/security folder

```
keytool -printcert -file ertytr.cer
```

Comment: well upon execution of the command keytool -list -keystore cacerts i get list all the certicates installed now from this list i want to see the complete details of the certificate named ertytr.cer